# Cod as a sub for salmon

Tags: substitutions, fish, salmon, cod

Will my recipe for roasted red pepper salmon still taste great with cod as a sub?

I have a freezer full of cod, but no salmon. The salmon goes faster. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Salmon is a much stronger flavor, to stand up to peppers.   So your dish will be different with cod; the only test is making it and seeing if you enjoy it.

Comment: Red pepper and cod isn't an unknown combination in Iberia.

Answer (score 1):

It might very well be delicious, the only way to really tell, is to try. However, keep in mind that cod has far less flavour, not to mention a significantly different flavour.

That said, I have substituted one for the other on several occasions, usually with decent results. The only exception to this has in my experience been when serving cod with very rich, fatty sauces, such as a hollandaise, which doesn't taste good to me at all. However, give me cod, melted butter, potatoes and chopped eggs, and I am a happy man.

At the end of the day, a big part of this is what you like. This might be completely delicious to you, or it might be a disappointment. Seeing how as you have "a freezer full of salmon", I'd say there's little harm in trying it once. If you don't like it, you can always do something else the next time.